# nth-child first and last both being applied to element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to write a selector for the following markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="one-third column">content</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="one-third column">content</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="one-third column">content</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

The selector should get the first .one-third.column and last .one-third.column and apply some custom CSS.

So far I've tried:

```
.row a > .one-third:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.row a > .one-third:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

However, this results in both of the above selectors being applied to each one-third element. I'm trying to achieve this without adding classes to the first and last element. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done however you need to select the first and last child of the link. If you are going inside of the link and selecting the first and last child of an element that there is only one, your required styling will not be able to work. If you select the first and last `a` tag, you'll get the desired outcome:

```css
.row a:first-child .one-third {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.row a:last-child .one-third {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="one-third column">content</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="one-third column">content</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="one-third column">content</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle to show this with background colours: https://jsfiddle.net/oprkd3vp/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent - this works perfectly. I'll accept this as the answer when enough time has elapsed.

Comment: Perfect, great to hear

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth-child(n) selector of css

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

```css
.row a:nth-child(1) {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.row a:nth-child(3) {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<a href="#">
    <div class="one-third column">content</div>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <div class="one-third column">content</div>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <div class="one-third column">content</div>
</a>
</div>
```